# C# GDI+ X-Y Axis questions

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

How does one find the coordinates halfway on the X and Y axis in a user control or form?

How can I identify the range of the X-axis and the Range of the Y axis on a user control or form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) property.

To find the range: do you mean the range on screen? if so, use the `RectangleToScreen` function.

To find the middle point, you can use

```
Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
Point p = new Point(
  (int)((r.X + r.Width) / 2),
  (int)((r.Y + r.Height) / 2));
```

Comment: Could this be used to find the range of the X-Y Axis or halfway point on either?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by 'axis', maybe you should clarify that a little.

Answer (score 1):

What does axis mean in your context?

Given the Height and Width properties, you should be able to work out the halfway position (remembering that Y is positive downwards!)

If, however, you are implementing axes in your own units, you will want to create some helper functions to convert from your units to pixels (and back, potentially)